# Tizen - How to respond to Web control's basic auth request programmatically

Tags: tizen

[API reference of ILoadingListener::OnHttpAuthenticationRequestedN](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.native.apireference/classTizen_1_1Web_1_1Controls_1_1ILoadingListener.html#a0b9fa79f86eeade9a307321ce0fc4119) says,

> Returns:
>   true if the ownership is taken by the application, 
>   else false, and a default dialog for the ID and password is displayed 
>   If this method returns true, the application must delete the AuthenticationChallenge instance.

But the instance of AuthenticationChallenge is passed as a const reference. How can I delete it? Also, [AuthenticationChallenge::Process()](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.native.apireference/classTizen_1_1Web_1_1Controls_1_1AuthenticationChallenge.html#ab1929407eba281afcae01ed482f2dbd7) is non-const function. How am I supposed to call it?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Tizen API. You should contact Tizen developers to explain this.

Comment: it happened for me before once, that API was broken - simillar to you some extra/missing const keywords. I've reported a bug and could only wait for fix in newer release

Comment: I didn't report bug with your problem. I had similar situation before you. You still need to contact tizen developers and fill bug report for your issue

Comment: Okay, sorry for misunderstanding.